# iOS SoundCloud stream from other users

Tags: ios, ios6, soundcloud

From what I have seen on these pages:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#

..https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI

They only describe ways to stream audio from one's own user account.

I am building an app that will take in requests from a website and pull soundcloud links from it, and the links are not from my own account. Is there a way to stream from random users with just a link given?

Further, when pulling data from the JSON API on the website, this is the string that I receive

> http://w.soundcloud.com//player//?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F53179275&show_artwork=true&auto_play=true\

Which is the result of the embed code for the song. Do I have to do anything to the URL to convert it to a different format?

And.... Is there a way to get the waveform to show up as well?

I am developing for ios6 and am on xcode 4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out for the most part.

The only part of the Souncloud API that I will be using is the registration on their website, to get the actual stream link I input this string with the two input variables of my client id and the track id that i pulled from the given link into my connection request:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/[track_id]@.json?client_id=[client_id]

This json also has the Waveform, I believe I will have to implement the player manually.

Anyone know of a good streaming player to use?

Comment: Figured out that I can use AVAudioPlayer. Trying to get it to work now.

Comment: Lets say I have the following stream url "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/53179275/stream" 

how do I get it to begin playing i have tried avaudioplayer, and avplayer. With AVaudioplayer I am currently getting this error: 

"Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)""

This is when I am using an url, that is converted into NSData.

Comment: I figured it out. one has to append the stated url above with @".json?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]"

Answer (score 0):

I use this for specific users.

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/[userid]/tracks.json?client_id=[client_id]&offset=20&limit=20
```

For Menu :

```
i.add(new NavItem("MENU TITLE", R.drawable.ic_details, NavItem.ITEM, SoundCloudFragment.class,
           new String[]{"USERID"}));
```